# how can i use twitter-bootsrap in rails 2.3.5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm pretty new in Rails and I want to know whether twitter-bootstrap is available for rails 2.3.5 with ruby version 1.8.7. How can I use it if twitter-bootstrap is available in lower versions of rails.

Comment: Since twitter-bootstrap is front-end framework, there's no reason it could be unavailable in Rails 2.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use any of the gems, which were created for later version of rails, to nicely integrate twitter-bootstrap into the asset pipeline.

In rails 2.3.5 you have no asset-pipeline, so it is in a sense much easier:

- download a distributable version of bootstrap
- place the css in `public/stylesheets`
- place the js in `public/javascript`
- include them in your `application.html.haml/erb`

Done :)

Comment: it worked. but how can i import bootstrap/responsive ?

Comment: Mmmm which version of bootstrap are you using? The responsive part is automatically included in v3. Or what do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

twitter-bootstrap is a css library and hence has no relation to the version of ruby or rails that you use. So the answer is, yes, bootstrap should work fine with any version of rails.